# why is my output repeated?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist

I've got it working, however the last Array, Sorted C Method outputs this:

```
SORTED C METHOD: 179, 181, 238, 190, 105, 144, 26, 63, 90, 14, SORTED C METHOD: 190, 238, 181, 179, 105, 144, 26, 63, 90, 14, SORTED C METHOD: 238, 190, 181, 179, 105, 144, 26, 63, 90, 14,
```

Why does it repeat so many times when Sorted A Method and Sorted B Method only output one occurence?
Below is the code:

Main Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreeSorts.SortA(randArray(0));
        System.out.println("\n");
        ThreeSorts.SortB(randArray(0));
        System.out.println("\n");
        ThreeSorts.SortC(randArray(0));
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> randArray(int n) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
        Random rand = new Random();
        rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());

        int[] x = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            Integer r = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 256);
            a.add(r);
        }
        showArray(a);
        return a;
    }

    public static void showArray(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        int n = a.size();
        System.out.println("RANDOM NUMBERS GENERATED 0 TO 255:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int r = a.get(i);
            System.out.print("|" + r + "| ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public static void showA(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
        int n = array.size();
        System.out.print("SORTED A METHOD: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int r = array.get(i);
            System.out.print(r + ", ");
        }
    }

    public static void showB(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
        int n = array.size();
        System.out.print("SORTED B METHOD: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int r = array.get(i);
            System.out.print(r + ", ");
        }
    }

    public static void showC(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
        int n = array.size();

        System.out.print("SORTED C METHOD: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int r = array.get(i);
            System.out.print(r + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Sorted Arrays Class:

```
import java.util.*;

pubic class ThreeSorts {
    private static ArrayList<Integer> CopyArray(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        ArrayList<Integer> resa = new ArrayList<Integer>(a.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
            resa.add(a.get(i));
        }
        return (resa);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> SortA(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        ArrayList<Integer> array = CopyArray(a);
        int n = a.size(), i;
        boolean noswaps = false;

        while (noswaps == false) {
            noswaps = true;
            for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
                if (array.get(i) < array.get(i + 1)) {
                    Integer temp = array.get(i);
                    array.set(i, array.get(i + 1));
                    array.set(i + 1, temp);
                    noswaps = false;
                }
            }
        }
        main.showA(array);
        return (array);

    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> SortB(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        ArrayList<Integer> array = CopyArray(a);
        Integer[] zero = new Integer[a.size()];
        Integer[] one = new Integer[a.size()];
        int i, b;
        Integer x, p;
        // Change from 8 to 32 for whole integers - will run 4 times slower
        for (b = 0; b < 8; ++b) {
            int zc = 0;
            int oc = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
                x = array.get(i);
                p = 1 << b;
                if ((x & p) == 0) {
                    zero[zc++] = array.get(i);
                } else {
                    one[oc++] = array.get(i);
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < oc; ++i)
                array.set(i, one[i]);
            for (i = 0; i < zc; ++i)
                array.set(i + oc, zero[i]);
        }
        main.showB(array);
        return (array);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> SortC(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        ArrayList<Integer> array = CopyArray(a);
        SortC(array, 0, array.size() - 1);
        return (array);
    }

    public static void SortC(ArrayList<Integer> array, int first, int last) {
        if (first < last) {
            int pivot = PivotList(array, first, last);
            SortC(array, first, pivot - 1);
            SortC(array, pivot + 1, last);
        }

    }

    private static void Swap(ArrayList<Integer> array, int a, int b) {
        Integer temp = array.get(a);
        array.set(a, array.get(b));
        array.set(b, temp);
    }

    private static int PivotList(ArrayList<Integer> array, int first, int last) {
        Integer PivotValue = array.get(first);
        int PivotPoint = first;
        for (int index = first + 1; index <= last; ++index) {
            if (array.get(index) > PivotValue) {
                PivotPoint = PivotPoint + 1;
                Swap(array, PivotPoint, index);
            }
        }
        main.showC(array);
        Swap(array, first, PivotPoint);
        return (PivotPoint);
    }
}
```

P.S. I am using Eclipse Java

Comment: Thanks for reformatting...that was making my eyes hurt!

Comment: Could this be tagged homework perhaps?

Comment: ive tried all the answers, still not working :-(

Comment: 'not working' isn't very useful. If you can give the stacktrace you're getting, then we can help you.

Comment: indeed, you should edit the question and post what you have tried with the results you have obtained.  Otherwise we can only guess as to what you are trying to do.  Help us help you !

Answer (score 1):

Your showC method call is the issue.Try this:

```
    public static void SortC(ArrayList<Integer> array, int first, int last) {
    if (first < last) {
        int pivot = PivotList(array, first, last);
        SortC(array, first, pivot - 1);
        SortC(array, pivot + 1, last);
    }
    main.showC(array)//this method has to be called only when your array has been sorted
    }
```

The issue with your code is,you are printing the array every time you are finding new pivot point.Hope this helps...Happy coding

Comment: that is the correct answer.  SortC(array, first, last) is a recursive function and will be called multiple times.  If you showC in there then it will show multiple times.  Same goes for the pivot List or swap functions.

Comment: "doesn't work either" then what was the output???was it the same? different? Explain it properly or it'll be difficult for you to find the correct "this worked" kind of solution. . .

Answer (score 1):

It's all about your `public static void SortC(ArrayList<Integer> array,int first,int last)`
method. It get called by multiple times, because of `Recursion`.

But if you wish to get the right out put in a wrong way then the below lines of code will help you. Inside `class ThreeSorts` define a variable such as

```
public static boolean isPrinted;
```

and update your PivotList() method as below given or just copy it any paste it will work.

```
private static int PivotList(ArrayList<Integer> array, int first, int last) {
        Integer PivotValue = array.get(first);
        int PivotPoint = first;
        for (int index = first + 1; index <= last; ++index) {
            if (array.get(index) > PivotValue) {
                PivotPoint = PivotPoint + 1;
                Swap(array, PivotPoint, index);
            }
        }
        if (!isPrinted) {
            Main.showC(array);
            isPrinted = true;
        }
        //Main.showC(array);
        Swap(array, first, PivotPoint);
        return (PivotPoint);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because SortC is called 3 times?

```
public static void SortC(ArrayList<Integer> array,int first,int last){
    if (first < last) {
        int pivot = PivotList(array,first,last);
        SortC(array,first,pivot-1);
        SortC(array,pivot+1,last);
     } 
}
```

- `SortC()` calls `PivotList()`
- `PivotList()` calls `showC()`
- `showC()` prints to SystemOut

I'd update your primary `SortC` method to do the printing, instead of the recursive method:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> SortC(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    ArrayList<Integer> array = CopyArray(a);
    SortC(array, 0, array.size() - 1);
    main.showC(array) // print only when finished sorting!
    return (array);
}
```

Comment: I believe this is just sorting the order of the numbers using the pivot sort method

Comment: you should explain what you have tried so far, how have you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: I've tried to add a dummy for loop to repeat it once only (for (int s=0; s<n; s++) but its repeated even more times.

Comment: The method SortC(ArrayList<Integer>) in the type ThreeSorts is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Integer>, int, int)

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done. I was only suggesting you remove the `main.showC()` from `SortC(ArrayList<Integer> array,int first,int last)` to `SortC(ArrayList<Integer> a)`

Answer (score 0):

As I stated bunch11 gave the correct answer, it is indeed because you are using ShowC within your argorithm that it gets called multiple times.

But this is only the symptom not the underlying issue.  Your problem here is that you create unnecessary coupling between your algorithm functions (the SortedArray class) and your utility functions (the main class).

In other words your SortedArrays class should not depend on the main class for anything thus nothing in the  SortedArrays class should be calling anything in the main.

If you make this very simple adjustment to your code by calling the show function in your main function and remove any mention of them in your SortedArrays class your code will display each  only once.

like so :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        showA(ThreeSorts.SortA(randArray(0)));
        System.out.println("\n");
        showB(ThreeSorts.SortB(randArray(0)));
        System.out.println("\n");
        showC(ThreeSorts.SortC(randArray(0)));
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

Then remove any main.showXXX from your other class.  This assume that each sort function returns the array.

This way each class has a single purpose and makes everything much easier to follow and understand.  Mixing purposes (sorting AND displaying) in the same function (or the same class in Object Oriented) often leads to side effects such as this.

Lastly I did not try to see if the algorithms are correct, I just concentrated on your code structure.  It is possible there are other errors, then again, it is a homework I can't do all the work for you :-)  That said you seem to be doing fine so I'm not too worried.